# Super considered super does not run for me

Tags: python

I am working through Raymond Hettinger's Youtube presentation [Raymond Hettinger - Super considered super! - PyCon 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo).

I have typed in the first example `pizza.py` which he uses where he's using python3.5.

```
class DoughFactory(object):

  def get_dough(self):
    return 'insecticide treated wheat dough'


class Pizza(DoughFactory):

  def order_pizza(self, *toppings):
    print('Getting Dough')
    dough = DoughFactory.get_dough()
    print('Making pie with %s' % dough)
    for topping in toppings:
      print('Adding: %s' % topping)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  Pizza().order_pizza("pepperoni", "Bell Pepper")
```

When I run it using python3.5 I get:

```
Getting Dough
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pizza.py", line 18, in <module>
    Pizza().order_pizza("pepperoni", "Bell Pepper")
  File "pizza.py", line 11, in order_pizza
    dough = DoughFactory.get_dough()
TypeError: get_dough() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I have also tried it with python3.9 and on two different computers with the same result.

Comment: You may have typed it in wrong. `dough = DoughFactory.get_dough()` should be `dough = DoughFactory().get_dough()` for it to work.

Comment: @AKX Raymond made the typo. Retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 0):

Raymond is actually the one doing the typo, but he never ran the code. Later he changed it. The correct implementation would be:

```
class DoughFactory(object):

    def get_dough(self):
        return 'insecticide treated wheat dough'


class Pizza(DoughFactory):

    def order_pizza(self, *toppings):
        print('Getting Dough')
        dough = DoughFactory.get_dough(self)
        print('Making pie with %s' % dough)
        for topping in toppings:
            print('Adding: %s' % topping)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Pizza().order_pizza("pepperoni", "Bell Pepper")
```

But as his talk is about, consider super instead to adhere to the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and for python to resolve the [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) with multiple inheritance.

```
class DoughFactory(object):

    def get_dough(self):
        return 'insecticide treated wheat dough'


class Pizza(DoughFactory):

    def order_pizza(self, *toppings):
        print('Getting Dough')
        dough = super().get_dough()
        print('Making pie with %s' % dough)
        for topping in toppings:
            print('Adding: %s' % topping)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Pizza().order_pizza("pepperoni", "Bell Pepper")
```

Also, [PEP8 (Python style guide)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#indentation) suggests using 4 spaces for indentation.

Comment: Because the intent is to *use `DoughFactory` as a base class*, rather than instantiating it, it makes more sense (and is more parallel with the `super` usage) to simply call `get_dough` to just use the normal lookup; or to explicitly specify the parent, `DoughFactory.get_dough(self)`. (Keep in mind that `super()` does not instantiate the parent class, but instead creates a special object that looks up the methods differently.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Oh, of course, it should be `DoughFactory.get_dough(self)`. Updated, thanks!